# How to use jquery .counterUp function in angular5?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

I want to create a counter up view for my company website, to do this i have to use jquery counterUp function.

Angular is not recognising the function even after adding script tags for it.

```
if(st >= hT ){
  $('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 2000
  });
```

The counter should start from zero and reach a certain defined number.

Comment: Using JQuery in Angular isn't a good practice. You can use ViewChild directives instead of JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the element referenced by ".counter" is an Angular component you should be using ViewChild instead of jQuery.

For example if the element was of class `Counter` then the likely better way to achieve this affect would be.

```
@ViewChild(Counter)
counter: Counter;
```

Then in the code block it would look like this.

```
if(st >= hT ){
  this.counter.counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 2000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1./ Install jQuery

> npm install jquery

2./ Open angular.json and find scripts

```
  "scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

3./ go to your component and on top declare this

```
declare var jQuery: any;
```

4./ and in side ngOnInit

```
  (function ($) {
     if(st >= hT ){
         $('.counter').counterUp({
           delay: 10,
           time: 2000
         });
  })(jQuery);
```